# I am coding a TextFormatter that replaces special characters with HTML tags

Tags: java, html

I am coding a TextFormatter that replaces special characters with HTML tags.

```
"_" = "< i >" and "< /i >"
"*" = "< b >" and "< /b >"
```

so.. my codes is as follows..

```
public String convertBold() {
    if (countStrings("_") % 2 == 1) 
        return 1;

    String tag = "<b>";
    String result = "";
    while (find String("_", psn) >= 2) {
        int newPsn = findString("_", psn);

        // Copy the code before the "_" into the result
        result = result + line.substring(psn, newPsn);

        // Add the tag and change the tag
        result = result + tag;
        if (tag.equals("<B>")) 
            tag = "</B>";
        else 
            tag = "<B>";

        //update the psn
        psn = newPsn++;
    }

    //copy the rest of the string
    result = result + line.substring(psn);
    return result;
}
```

What I need help with is that nesting tags in HTML can cause errors. I don't understand how to properly nest tags in HTML since if I don't close a tag before inserting a new one it causes it an error. I know the way I phrase this could make it slightly confusing but I would appreciate any help and if I can answer any question to clean up any confusion let me know.

Thank you in advance! - Vexial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your markup text is correct:

```
/**
*@param s string to HTML
*
*/
String convert(String s){
  while(s.indexOf("_")!= -1 ||s.indexOf("*") != -1){
           if(s.indexOf("_") != -1){
               s = s.replaceFirst("\\_", "<i>");
               s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("_"))+"</i>"+s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_")+1);
           } 

           if(s.indexOf("*") != -1){
               s = s.replaceFirst("\\*", "<b>");
               s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("*"))+"</b>"
               +s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("*")+1);
           } 

     }//end while

return s;
}
```